# How to get month from mssql datetime in javascript

Tags: javascript, sql-server

I have datetime with this format -

```
Nov 17 2014 02:06:57:000PM
```

but, i can't convert this to js datetime.

I have used the `split()` function to get the day, year and time successfully, but I don't know how to get month from this format.

Comment: why don't you return only month from your sql query ?

Comment: i can't. I need in month day and year

Comment: what you are expecting ? a date in mm/dd/yyyy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this.  **[JSFiddler Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n8zbocrj/3/)**

```
 var d = new Date('Nov 17 2014 02:06:57:000 PM');
 var n = d.getMonth() + 1;
```

If you date string is `'Nov 17 2014 02:06:57:000PM'`

```
var s = 'Nov 17 2014 02:06:57:000PM';
var result = s.substr(0, s.indexOf('M') - 1) + ' ' 
             + s.substr(s.indexOf('M') - 1, s.length) ; 
var d = new Date(result);
var n = d.getMonth() + 1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

var Month = new Date('Nov 17 2014 02:06:57:000 PM').getMonth()+1;

I am adding +1 because Counting of Months starts from 0 so for January it will take 0 and so on.